# Please explain this optical phenomenon seen in a glass cup filled with water

Tags: optics, everyday-life, reflection

The photo shows a clear glass cup viewed from above.

When empty only the central ring at the base of the cup is visible, as well as the rim at the top. The sides of the cup are clear.

Then I poured some water into the cup. A number of other concentric circles appeared, which appear to be multiple reflections of the circular base in the sides of the glass cup.

What causes these images to appear when water is poured into the cup?

[image]

Comment: @Aaryan Dewan: they sure look like Newton's rings, which is an interference effect; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_rings.  This would require that the water be still, and a curved surface at the bottom.

Comment: Is it what you think it is ? Please show a side view of the glass.

Comment: I can't see anything that even remotely resembles Newton's rings in that image. The multiple reflections seem to be between the surfaces of the wall of the glass itself (similar patterns can be seen when looking along a planar slate of glass, in a shallow angle the reflection of the surface goes up significantly allowing pronounced multiple reflections – similar to two parallel mirrors). The water simply allows you to see them by effectively changing the angle in which you look upon the walls due to refraction.

Comment: @PeterDiehr  I do not think they can be Newton's rings as they are not coloured and for white light only a few rings with colour would be seen.

Comment: I'm not even sure what is being observed here.

Comment: Very interesting.  Can you upload a photograph of the glass from the side?